# Adding ng-minlength to input field

Tags: angularjs

I'm attempting to add ng-minlength and ng-maxlength to a form input field. There is something strange happening. When the a number is entered is less than the min-length it disappears and is never added to the model.

However if you past in a number over 13 digits it renders but is not added to the model.

```
    app.directive('cmNumber', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function (element) {
            var onlyNumbers = /^\d+$/;
            element.attr('ng-minlength', '13');
            element.attr('ng-maxlength', '19');
            element.attr('ng-pattern', onlyNumbers);

            element.attr('placeholder', '123456789112345');
            element.removeAttr('cm-Number'); //remove the attribute to avoid infinite loop

            return function (scope, element) {
                    $compile(element[0].form)(scope);
                };
        }
    };
}]);
```

plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/G4DaGSt190NTdaognJrJ?p=preview

Comment: Why are you using `compile` rather than adding these values to the template?

Answer (score 1):

Only you need to do change is `cm-number` instead of `cm-Number` all should be in small case.

Otherwise your code is totally correct. The reason behind above directive is not working is You are referring to angular beta version `1.3.0-beta.5` which has possibly has broken the thing which you are trying.

You should upgrade it to `angular 1.3.15` that is stable version also you could go for angular latest `angular 1.4+` versions

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6XsY1QIIERhYiRy2NAX9?p=preview)

Comment: Yes looks like a bug in that version. Unfortunately the project I'm working on uses angular 1.2.28.